# writing a banded matrix in a row major layout for lapack solver dgbsv

Tags: linear-algebra, intel-mkl, lapacke

I want to solve this linear system Ax=b, where:

```
A =  
    [-0.23  2.54  -3.66  0;  
     -6.98  2.46  -2.73  -2.73;  
      0     2.56   2.46   4.07;  
      0     0     -4.78   3.82]

b = [4.42 27.13 -6.14  10.5]
```

and the solution should be

```
x = [-2  3  1  -4]
```

which is a banded matrix with lower band equals to 1 and upper band equals to 2

It is solved using DGBSV solver as follows

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mkl_lapacke.h"
#define N 4
int main() { 
    int i;
    MKL_INT ipiv[N];
    double a[16] = { 0,    -0.23,  2.54, -3.66,
                    -6.98,  2.46, -2.73, -2.13,
                     2.56,  2.46,  4.07,  0,
                    -4.78,  3.82,  0,     0};

    double b[4] =  {4.42, 27.13, -6.14, 10.5};

    LAPACKE_dgbsv( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, 1, 2, 1, a, N, ipiv, b, 1);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf("%f\n", b[i]);
}
```

The code is aborting at the dgbsv solver. When I write matrices a and b pointers it gives the values of the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the input stated in your question, i.e.,

```
A =  
[-0.23  2.54  -3.66  0;  
 -6.98  2.46  -2.73  -2.73;  
  0     2.56   2.46   4.07;  
  0     0     -4.78   3.82]

b = [4.42 27.13 -6.14  10.5]
```

the solution (solving the system as a dense one) I get is:

```
[-3.77599, -1.28156, -1.85975, 0.421568]
```

However, as for the code, there are several things worth mentioning. What the function [`LAPACKE_dgbsv`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/ddf/lapacke__dgbsv_8c_a84fd8b92816876c9c6c20608a1362aa5.html#a84fd8b92816876c9c6c20608a1362aa5) essentially does is that it checks the validity of the input and in turn calls the function [`LAPACKE_dgbsv_work`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/de/ddd/lapacke_8h_a3fe9807c0e4d0686f98436e76dca5677.html#a3fe9807c0e4d0686f98436e76dca5677). If this function detects that the supplied layout is `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR`, it merely transposes its input (matrix, right-hand sides) and passes all this to `LAPACKE_dgbsv` which expects column-major version of the [packed matrix](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node124.html).

So, if your code specifies `LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR`, the array `a` should contain row-major version of the packed matrix as specified in the link above. Also, perhaps more importantly, `LAPACKE_dgbsv` requires additional space in the array `a` so that it can store the result of the LU decomposition. Specifically, there have to be additional `kl` rows.

Thus

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mkl_lapacke.h"
#define N 4
int main() {

    int i;
    MKL_INT ipiv[N];

    double b[4] =  {4.42, 27.13, -6.14, 10.5};

    double a[] = {
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, -3.66, -2.73,
        0, 2.54, -2.73, 4.07,
        -0.23, 2.46, 2.46, 3.82,
        -6.98, 2.56, -4.78, 0};

    MKL_INT info = LAPACKE_dgbsv(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, 1, 2, 1, a, N, ipiv, b, 1);
    //printf("%d\n", info);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++) printf("%f\n", b[i]);
}
```

then produces:

```
-3.775989
-1.281561
-1.859751
0.421568
```

which agrees with the solution obtained with the dense solver.

Comment: but I think that LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR means that I have to put matrix a in row major layout as specified in this link https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520871 and that is what I did

Comment: @mahmoudayyad I think that that link is a bit confusing - the row/column-major scheme is used in fact twice - for packing the band matrix (choosing the method) and then also for storing this packed matrix in a linear array - the first parameter of `LAPACKE_dgbsv` merely determines how is this packed matrix stored but not how it was packed...

Comment: here it is even shown explicitly: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522247 (there the image also shows the necessity to reserve space for additional `kl` rows, where `kl` is the number of subdiagonals)

Comment: The formulation you said worked... But when I try to use this technique in order to to solve cblas_dgbmv for matrix vector multiplication of the same two vectors... It gave wrong answer...

Comment: @mahmoudayyad how does the call to `cblas_dgbmv` look like in your code?

Comment: I found the matrix formulation of CBLAS differs from LAPACKE I don't know the reason... The LAPACKE must have a "kl" rows above the matrix and should be written as you specified... While cblas must be written as I wrote it in the question... I don't know the reason for this confusing

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is that [gbsv](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468882) functions expect matrix A to have space for 2KL + KU + 1 rows, whereas your code allocates only KL + KU + 1 rows. If this is wrong guess, you can look at the implementation of LAPACKE_dgbsv wrapper [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d94/lapacke__dgbsv__work_8c_source.html).